# Java: Парсинг xml

Tags: xml, sax, java, dom

Хочу увидеть наиболее простой и компактный алгоритм парсинга xml в java.
Любые библиотеки, классы. м?

Comment: Вам что то полезное сделать или динозавра поймать?

Comment: сугубо исследовательское желание =) 
Скорее по динозаврам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нету ни проще, ни лучше ни хуже ))) Есть только суровая реальность, но если верить Будде то и ее нет. Если вам надо вытаскивать в несколько заходов инфу из одного и того же XML документа то скорее всего дешевле по ресурсам построить дерево DOM. Если вся информация выбирается в один проход, то задачу скорее эффективнее решить при помощи обработки потока SAX.

Для игры с экзотикой к регулярным выражениям упомянутым выше предлагаю добавить antlr или что нибудь аналогичное )))

P.S. Все помнят анекдот про мужика на белазе?

Answer (score 4):

Единого общепринятого средства для  парсинга XML в java нет,
поэтому перечислю  наиболее распространенные парсеры:

**DOM** (Document Object Model – объектная модель документов) – платформенно-независимый программный интерфейс, позволяющий программам и скриптам управлять содержимым документов HTML и XML, а также изменять их структуру и оформление. Модель DOM не накладывает ограничений на структуру документа. Любой документ известной структуры с помощью DOM может быть представлен в виде дерева узлов, каждый узел которого содержит элемент, атрибут, текстовый, графический или любой другой объект. Узлы связаны между
собой отношениями родитель-потомок

[SAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAX) (Simple API for XML) - событийно-ориентированное API.
способ последовательного чтения/записи XML-файлов.

Обычно SAX-парсеры требуют фиксированного количества памяти для своей работы, но не позволяют изменять содержимое документа. Всё, что делает SAX-парсер, это сообщает вызвавшему приложению о встреченных распознанных элементах XML-разметки или о встреченных ошибках.

[JDOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDOM) (Java Document Object Model) - это свободная Java-реализация DOM для XML, созданная с учётом особенностей языка и платформы Java. JDOM интегрируется с Document Object Model (DOM) и Simple API for XML (SAX), поддерживает XPath и XSLT. В JDOM используются внешние парсеры для генерации документов. JDOM

[StAX](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-stax1/) - Потоковый API для XML. Представляет собой самый последний стандарт обработки данных XML в языке Java. Как поточный метод, он часто оказывается лучшей альтернативой, чем другие методы, например, DOM и SAX, и в отношении производительности, и в отношении удобства в работе.

Все парсеры имеют свои особенности:

- по разбору элементов,
- по возможностям изменениям элементов в документе
- по алгоритму
  перехода между элементами (DOM, например, читает документ полностью и
  лишь после этого приступает к его разбору, a SAX разбирает документ
  по частям)
- по наличию алгоритма валидации документов (не все парсеры позволяют проверять документ на правильность и валидность, например по схеме XSD)
- и многие многие другие особенности...

Все особенности этих парсеров влияют на их производительность, чем больше наворотов парсера тем медленнее он работает...

Иногда нужно разбирать документ полностью, иногда нужно найти все элементы определенного типа, а иногда только один элемент в документе.

Какой парсер выбрать, нужно решать в  зависимости от поставленной задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Какой парсинг вам нужен? Если DOM, то используйте стандартный способ:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file)
```

Можно ещё воспользоваться [domj4](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html) Но на мой взгляд выигрыш невелик, а библиотеку дополнительную тащить не очень хочется.

Если потоковый, так вы сами ответили на свой вопрос: используйте SAX

Comment: Отличный инструмент...  Когда-то в студенчестве, я  с его использованием курсовой делал.  Он очень прост в освоении )))
Спасибо, что напомнили!

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Digester](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/download_digester.cgi), парсинг пишется в 3 строчки.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ. Я хочу услышать какие-нибудь другие методы разбора xml помимо дом и сакс, может дико экзотические. Я сам пользую

SAX:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(""));

SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);
factory.setSchema(schema);
```

DOM:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
```

Это не ново и в интернете навалом. Может есть какая-нибудь библиотека или мега класс, который по-иному работает с xml.

Comment: Ну так и вот.. куда уж короче.. можно спрятать лишние слова куда-нибудь.. сделать какой-нибудь ParsersFactory и везде будет совсем коротко

Comment: окей, не используя ни дом и сакс

Comment: Так не бывает :) XML парсят двумя путями.. либо потоковым, либо построением дерева (который в свою очередь использует внутри себя потоковый парсер). По этой причине все способы будут аналогичны и различаться будут лишь в названиях и мелочах. Так что будут те же яйца только в профиль :) Есть ещё только один альтернативный вариант: можно прогнать XML через XSLT трансформацию и сгенерировать что-нибудь другое и парсить уже это что-то другое, но это уже изврат.

Comment: Я сомневаюсь что только два, xml в крипте - обычный файл с данными, и разборов этих данных может быть столько же много, сколько и решений обычных мат задач, вопрос просто в популярности и оптимизации

Comment: Ну есть другие решения, но они обычно ненадёжные. Такие как, например, разбор с помощью регулярных выражений. Он возможен, но решает задачу лишь частично и ненадёжен.

Comment: Если хотите экзотики - делайте парсинг через регулярные выражения...  или напишите свой парсер!
А если серьезно...   то лучше использовать инструменты которые имеют  широкое распространение (SAX бесспорно такой), потому что вы напишите программу и все будет хорошо...  до тех пор, пока ее не передадите другому программисту  на тех. поддержку...

Answer (score 0):

Всегда пользовался библиотекой JDOM, все намного проще (:

Answer (score -1):

Тема обсуждаласт также в топике ["Обработчик xml в Java."](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16790/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-xml-%D0%B2-java). Предлагаю посмотреть на StAX.