# Как распарсить XML инструментами Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

Всем доброго дня.
Помогите с решением проблемы парсинга xml без тегов, т.е. когда отсутствует древовидная структура. Например:

```
<Сотрудники>
<Сотрудник ДатаРождения="01.01.1955 0:00:00" ДатаПриема="01.11.2010 
0:00:00" Должность="Старший специалист техподдержки" ФИО="Иванов 
Александр Алексеевич"/>
<Сотрудник ДатаРождения="02.02.1977 0:00:00" ДатаПриема="01.12.2011 
0:00:00" Должность="Системный администратор" ФИО="Петров Алексей 
Андреевич"/>
</Сотрудники>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java: Парсинг xml](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/10688/java-%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-xml)

Comment: В DOM данные забираются по узлам, у меня же их нет. Как парсить, делить строку сплитами? Регулярным выражением разбирать?

Comment: Марш читать книгу по XML! То, что показано - стандартный древовидный xml с тегами (элементами). И с атрибутами. Важно: элемент != атрибут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
String body = "содержимое xml";

DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes()));

NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Сотрудник");
for(int x=0,size= nodeList.getLength(); x<size; x++) {
      System.out.println(nodeList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Должность").getNodeValue())
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ